# after commiting in aws.yml the following error occurs

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

[image]

i am deploying mern app to aws ec2 by github actions workflows
i am getting  this error following arguments are required --aplication name

[image]

and this is my aws.yml file for workflow i am new to aws pls suggest a way to solve this error

Comment: My guess is you're using the wrong line break character. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790454/184546) for more info. (Maybe just get rid of the '\'...)

Comment: Don't post images of text (see [ask]). This isn't a Git issue, though: Git doesn't use yaml files for anything. Some providers (GitHub, AWS, etc) have add-ons that do use yaml, so this is either a github or aws thing (so I'll snip only the [tag:git] tag, the remaining tags are right).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines)